# How to use a function with a set variable in PHP?

Tags: php, sql

I have this function in a separate .php file:

```
function getBasicHerpInfo($offset='0'){
    # Get the details of two herps from the database, offset by $offset
    $sql = "SELECT NUM, COLOR, COST
            FROM HERPES
            ORDER BY NUM
            LIMIT $offset,2";
    return DBIface::connect()->query($sql);
}
```

So what it apparently does it get the details of two herps. I want to display the details of two herps on each page, and the details that are displayed changes because of a variable called $offset, rather than making a new page for each pair of herps. This is also useful when I want to add more herps to the database without making a new page, it should just work.

So my problem is, I'm not sure how to properly pass the variable $offset into the function, because it seems it is already set? Is it a default, or do I have to pass it into the function in some special way?

Comment: You pass it as an parameter when you call this function. If nothing is passed then `0` is used as a default value.

Answer (score 1):

The declaration:

```
function getBasicHerpInfo($offset='0') { ... }
```

is setting a default value to `$offset` of `0`. This means, if you call

```
getBasicHerpInfo();
```

then `$offset` will be set to 0. You can override the default by calling

```
getBasicHerpInfo(5); // or other number
```

which will give `$offset` a value of 5. In short, you only need to pass a parameter to the function if you want `$offset` to have a value other the default setting of 0.

Comment: @CreativeMind I didn't think they were necessary to make my point, but I went ahead and added them to clear up any confusion.

Comment: Just as an extra thing, can you tell me how to iterate through the results using a foreach loop, or do you have a better way?

Comment: @LaneWalker Probably something like `$data = getBasicHerpInfo()->fetchAll(); foreach($data as $row){print_r($row);}`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are right. If function call fails to pass any value to the fucntion, then the assignment is used a "default value" for the variable, but please try changing:

```
function getBasicHerpInfo($offset='0') { ... }
```

To

```
function getBasicHerpInfo($offset=0) { ... }
```